# Border layout with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment, border-layout, vertical-text

Is it possible to build a border layout with bootstrap, that centers the labels of the right and left borders, keeps the bottom  at the bottom of the page and fills the content with all space left over in the center?

New to bootstrap, but even with the help of google I just came up with this:

```
div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="left-box">
            <div class="turn-left">left</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="top-box">top</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="content-box">content</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="bottom-box">bottom</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="right-box">
            <div class="turn-right">right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fbtw6/352

The result is not very convincing - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See it [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6d1bve1/) works for you.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <div class="left-box">
                    <div class="turn-left">left</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="top-box">top</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="content-box">content</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <div class="right-box">
                    <div class="turn-right">right</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p>sticky footer</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

I used this [**example**](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) to assemble.

Like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6d1bve1/1/) any better?

Comment: Partly, yes, thanks a lot - but how would I get the footer between the left and right panels? When I tried, it went up again.

And there's still the vertical alignment of the labels in the left and right.

Comment: Yes - Wow, great - exactly!
Not Bootstrap cols, but that's fine, I'm going to work from there.